# How to use Selenium webdriver in Python to extract texts?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to extract all sponsors' info from https://www.terrapinn.com/conference/telecoms-world-asia/sponsors-and-exhibitors.stm and I've tried the coding below. But seems doesn't work. Can anyone let me know how to change the code?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'xxx\chromedriver.exe')
UTX_URL = 'https://www.terrapinn.com/conference/telecoms-world-asia/speakers.stm'
driver.get(UTX_URL)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='SponsorListing']").text.split('\n')
```

The above code doesn't return what I expected. I want to find all the sponsors' info (highlighted):
[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all the sponsors' info from `https://www.terrapinn.com/conference/telecoms-world-asia/sponsors-and-exhibitors.stm` you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.terrapinn.com/conference/telecoms-world-asia/sponsors-and-exhibitors.stm")
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.modal-body p")])
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.terrapinn.com/conference/telecoms-world-asia/sponsors-and-exhibitors.stm")
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-body']//p")])
    ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Chat Union Climaveneta Co., Ltd. is Hong Kong based Regional Sales &amp; Services Headquarter for Southeast Asia market, which specialized in hydronic systems for air conditioning and heating and IT cooling solutions. Our brands share the mission of ...', 'Mavenir is the industry’s only end-to-end, Cloud Native Network Software Provider, redefining network economics for Communication Service Providers (CSPs). Our innovative solutions pave the way to 5G with 100% software-based, end-to-end, Cloud...', 'Metaswitch is the world’s leading cloud native communications software company. The company develops commercial and open-source software solutions that are constructively disrupting the way that service providers build, scale, innovate and account...', 'ServiceNow (NYSE: NOW) is making the world of work, work better for people. Their cloud based platform and solutions deliver digital workflows that create great experiences and unlock productivity for employees and the enterprise.', "Zendrive is a mission-driven company, working to make roads safer with data and analytics. Powered by the world's largest data set of more than 180 billion mobile driving miles, Zendrive uses AI and machine learning to improve fleet safety and...", 'MarvelTec is an independent international connectivity catalyst and the exclusive partner of Deutsche Telekom Global Carrier in the Asia Pacific region. We combine deep corporate and multinational know-how with extensive Asian cultural intelligence...', 'Netrounds provides a software-based and fully automatable solution for active network testing and monitoring with unmatched measurement capabilities across physical and multi-cloud network environments. Netrounds is easily deployed at any location...', '10T Tech is a GSMA compliant eSIM service provider, focusing on the challenger , ‘virtual’ mobile carriers, and device manufacturers through innovative and aggressive commercial and technical value proposition. Through our innovative commercials we...', "Telecom companies are getting millions of calls, and over half of those are 'how to' questions, many of which are answered in the documentation. But customers rather not do something that takes time and effort, like reading...", 'Aprecomm’s Virtual Wireless Expert (VWE) product offers a solution to the industry that\n\nimproves and enhances Wi-Fi Experience in Enterprise, SMB (Small Medium Business), Retail\n\nand SP (Service Provider) markets.\n\n&nbsp;\n\nThough the Wi-Fi protocols...', 'With 20 years of global expertise serving telcos and hosting providers worldwide, atmail helps companies use email hosting to increase customer engagement and brand revenue. Powering 170 million mailboxes worldwide, atmail offers a...', 'Botnoi Consulting focuses in localising AI i.e. to specific languages and specific business domains. We provide consultation and implementation in Chatbots, AI, and Data Science. We also have a few SAAS platforms for public to access our AI...', 'Finema is building Enterprise Decentralized Identity platform for providing a verification system to verify documents, assets, and human.Our customers are Enterprise and Government- We help them to handle huge user database with decentralized...', 'FNT is a leading provider of integrated software solutions for telecommunication infrastructure management, IT management and data center infrastructure management worldwide. FNT’s innovative software solutions are used worldwide as an OSS / IT...', 'Goama or GoGames is like Netflix, but for mobile games based on android and subscription. Our solution allows customers in emerging markets to play the very best games, with zero friction. Previously access to the great mobile games was...', 'HORISEN is a product-oriented software company specialized in developing cutting-edge cloud products in the area of Telecom and Marketing. We develop software solutions for Mobile Operators, Voice Carriers, SMS Aggregators, OTTs and Enterprises of...', 'The IEEE Xplore® Digital Library is your gateway to trusted research— journals, conferences, standards, ebooks, analytics solutions and educational courses—with over 4.7 million articles to help you fuel imagination, build from previous...', 'InSync Information Technologies Pvt Ltd is a products &amp; services company that focuses on network automation and orchestration solutions across service providers and large enterprises. Its trademark product; InSync Automation Engine is a vendor...', 'International Gateway or IG is a subsidiary company of ALT Telecom PLC who is a neutral regional player in Telecom business who provides Telecom infrastructure and services to support both Domestic and Overseas Telecom Services Provider.&nbsp;IG was...', 'MeiG Smart Technology Co., Ltd was founded in 2007. With headquarter in Shenzhen city, Bao’an District, we set up research and development center also in Shanghai city, Xi’an city and Wuhan city. The employees number is over 2500, and nearly 600 of...', 'Mylinex International is a Telecommunications solutions vendor that is trusted by Multinational Mobile Network Operators &nbsp;all over the world that specializes in signaling, VAS and core solutions. Today our solutions have spanned into multiple...', 'A leading global vendor for B/OSS &amp; OCS and UCaaS, PortaOne is trusted by telecom operators for over 20 years. We build software to make communications reliable, affordable and easy to use. Our products empower telecom operators to improve...', 'QLC Chain is to resolve the data trust and security problem in the communication industry, and aims to build a public chain for Network-as-a-Service (NaaS) platform.&nbsp;From the ledger structure perspective: QLC Chain supports each account to have its...', 'About Symphony Communication Public Company Limited:Symphony Communication Public Company Limited is a Domestic and International Telecom Network Provider in Thailand. It was established in November 2005 and has been listed in the stock exchange of...', 'Vertiv brings together hardware, software, analytics and ongoing services to ensure its customers’ vital applications run continuously, perform optimally and grow with their business needs. Vertiv solves the most important challenges facing today’s...', 'Thailand Convention &amp; Exhibition Bureau (TCEB) continues to shape the business events industry of Thailand with exceptional acumen and effective solutions. With a robust service support system and innovative approaches to co-create distinctive...', 'The Action Community for Entrepreneurship (ACE) is a national private sector-led organisation to build a dynamic and impactful connected startup ecosystem from Singapore. Launched in 2003 by the Ministry of Trade &amp; Industry and restructured as a ...', 'Bridge Alliance is the leading mobile alliance for premier operators and their customers in the Asia Pacific, Middle East and Africa. Our alliance covers 34 members who serve more than 800 million customers collectively across these regions.&nbsp;Our...', 'What’s the Franco-Thai Chamber of Commerce (FTCC)?- A non-profit bilateral organization based in Bangkok- A link between France and Thailand in terms of economy, business and more - A partner of choice with more than 300 members in various sectors...', 'Council advises you on Ecosystem management.We help you build quality relationships with all stakeholders by developing a conversation.', 'The Thai-Italian Chamber of Commerce is a private, non-profit organization which has a network of member companies from all around the world with its headquarters in Bangkok, Thailand. The main goal of the Chamber is to enhance cooperation between...', 'Vietnam Internet Association (VIA) was established in October, 2010, operating on nongovernmental and not-for-profit basis. VIA currently has more than 100 organizational members, including telcos, ISPs, communication, digital content...', 'ACN Newswire provides full service, real time press release distribution for companies and organizations wishing to disclose and disseminate information to media, business, and the financial markets worldwide.&nbsp; ACN Newswire distributes press...', 'APAC CIOoutlook is a print magazine that aims to provide a platform for CIOs, CTOs, and other senior level IT buyers and decision makers along with CXOs of solution providers to share their experiences,&nbsp;wisdom, and advice with enterprise IT...', 'Asia Outlook is a digital and print product aimed at boardroom and hands-on decision-makers across a wide range of industries on the continent. With content compiled by our experienced production team ensuring delivery to the highest standards, we...', 'Business Chief Asia is a leading business website that focuses on news, articles, exclusive interviews and reports on Asian companies across key subjects such as leadership, technology, sustainability, marketing and finance. Business Chief Asia is...', "CIO Advisor APAC is published from the hub of technology, Silicon Valley, USA, with an editorial presence in all major APAC countries.Our mission is to enable CIO's of medium to large enterprises based in APAC countries to leverage technology...", 'The Connect-World magazines are a forum for the highest-level ICT decision makers, to discuss the impact of ICT upon regional development.Connect-World publishes editions for Asia-Pacific, AME, EMEA, Europe, India, Latin America, North America, and...', 'CrmXchange has developed unique industry insights into the business intelligence and professional programs required for successful operations. Known by our audience as the “event site,” we are experts in webcast hosting. Visitors to the site can...', 'Developing Telecoms is the web portal for mobile and telecoms in emerging markets worldwide. We keep visitors up-to-date with opportunities, technologies, products and services that are transforming communications and empowering communities. Our...', 'Disruptive.Asia covers the current state of digital disruption in the Asia-Pacific telecommunications industry – where it’s coming from, what’s driving it, the impact it’s having on the industry, how telecoms players are responding and what’s...', 'Gigabit is a digital information and media platform for executives and leaders, providing expert insight into the ever expanding space occupied by technology in business.Packed with deep features and insight from key leaders in business, Gigabit...', 'HomeGrid Forum (HGF) is an industry alliance that brings together the world’s best in technology innovators, silicon vendors, system manufacturers, and service providers to promote G.hn, a globally recognized gigabit home networking technology based ...', 'InfoCom is a market research and consultancy company with 30 years of experience in providing expert strategic planning assistance to stakeholders in the telecommunications, IT and multimedia industries across the globe.Our group is one of the few - ...', 'InnovationManagement.se is one of the internet’s preeminent resources for innovation news and best practices. The content on the site is written for and by professionals who are working in the field of innovation. They are interested in learning how ...', 'Interface&nbsp;Magazine&nbsp;from B2e Media is a dedicated media platform for CIOs, CTOs, and digital and technology executives, providing a definitive guide to digital disruption and technology transformation alongside the wider role technology plays in...', 'MarketsandMarkets™ provides quantified B2B research on 30,000 high-growth niche opportunities/threats which will impact 70% to 80% of worldwide companies’ revenues. Currently, we offer services to 7500 customers worldwide, including 80% of global...', 'Connecting security and technology professionals to the latest events, education and technology across a global security domain.', 'A dedicated media provider for security and technology professionals, as well as end-users across multiple channels. Stay updated by downloading the MySecurity Media app now!', 'Optical Connections has been providing the fibre optic community with essential industry news and reports since 2011. Covering the technologies, products and commercial prospects currently influencing the market, through a combination of a quarterly ...', 'Pravasi Express -The leading Indian lifestyle news portal publishing from Singapore.&nbsp;Visit: www.pravasiexpress.com', 'Smart Insights, by Intelling: a blog about the Secure Transactions industry. Smart Insights covers the smart card and secure transactions industry, its businesses, its technologies, its markets as well as its technology suppliers. Smart Insights...', 'SupplyChainBrain, the world’s most comprehensive supply chain management information resource, is accessed year round through a wide range of ever evolving multi-media formats by hundreds of thousands of senior level industry executives. In addition ...', 'TelcoProfessionals(TP) is an interactive, content rich, blog- and video-centric online community, and business exchange, developed exclusively for the Telecom and Media&nbsp;industry.&nbsp;We are dedicated to individuals working in the industry globally, as a ...', 'Telecoms Business provides updates on the ICT industry and focuses on information technology solutions and their application in the large business and government sectors in Africa and internationally.', 'With the aim to be the source of business intelligence for telecoms companies, government and other industry players within Asia Pacific and India regions, Telecom Review APAC publication covers all telecom’s news, industry trends, operator and...', 'Telecompaper is a respected, well known and independently operating press agency and market research firm, with a dedicated focus on the international Technology, Media and Telecommunications sector (TMT). Telecompaper has a global focus...', 'TelecomWatch is the only “Publishing-House” in India which is fully &amp; totally focused / concentrated on Indian Telecom &amp; its related industries. TelecomWatch serves well over 71,000 email ids &amp; its products are seen daily by more than...', 'Total Telecom meets the information and research needs of the Global Communications industry, from breaking news to expert analysis. It is the leading communications link between end users and the vendors, carriers and resellers of...']
  ```

Comment: Thank you. The code works so well. But because I am new to Selenium, can I know what are the options for? And why you added a "//p" to "//div[@class='modal-body']" for the xpath?

Comment: @Bangbangbang Didn't understand what you meant by `options`. If you observe the HTML, each of the required information is within a _Modal Dialog Box_, precisely within the _Modal Body_, within the `<p>` node. Let me know if any questions.